# How to catch expander header button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, button, expander

I have an expander with button on the expander headers. I would like to know on which expanders header is clicked the button, because i should modify the data on the button_click event. If I Don`t have binded it with a View Model

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True">
    <Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="btnAllDone" Click="btnAllDone_Click  >Close
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

AND this is the click event

```
private void btnAllDone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "All", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    switch (result)
    {
        case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
            try
            {

            //AND HERE I WANT TO MODIFY THE DATA(MYOBJECT) OF THE CURRENT EXPANDER HEADER GROUP
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            break;
        case MessageBoxResult.No:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like expander, button, and event handler correspond 1-to-1. so assign Name to expander, and use it in event handler:

```
<Expander x:Name="expanderAllDone" IsExpanded="True">
    <Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Name="btnAllDone" Content="Close" Click="btnAllDone_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander>
```

```
private void btnAllDone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "All", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
    if (result != MessageBoxResult.Yes) 
        return;

    try
    {
        expanderAllDone.IsExpanded = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added Name property, and when i call it from cs it shows that the name dowsn`t exist in the current context. I want to  get the values of that expander and add to myobject.

Comment: do you perhaps have some kind of Template in xaml?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could add Expander's name property so that way you could check which of the expanders event is generated

Comment: I edited the question, and then how do i call it from the click event? thanks for the time

Comment: you can cast sender to Button class if i understand correctly.it would be 
 'Button expander = (Button) sender'

And then you could check then expander.Name property if you would give it to your expander

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
private static T GetParent<T>(DependencyObject child) where T : class
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    if (parent == null) return null;
    else if (parent is T) return parent as T;
    else return GetParent<T>(parent);
}

private void btnAllDone_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get current button
    var button = (Button)sender;

    // Get current expander
    var expander = GetParent<Expander>(button);

    // Toggle expander
    expander.IsExpanded = !expander.IsExpanded;
}
```